# Why ThreadLocal doesn't create in new thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

The class Collector was created to generate the map with values (for example).
Need that Collector contains the resource, where haves access only by the current thread.

The class Collector is presented below:

```
public class Collector    
    {
        ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>> storage;
        public Map<String, String> collection(int id) {
            storage = new ThreadLocal<>();
            storage.set(new HashMap<>());
            for (int i = id * 100; i <= id * 1000; i+=id * 100)
            {
                storage.get().put(String.valueOf(i), "test");
            }
            return storage.get();
        }
    }
```

I try to execute method `collection(int id)` at the same time in different threads. My suggestion is based [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). But sometimes thrown **NullPointerException**, my observations point out on re-creating ThreadLocal by another Thread, so **NullPointerException** throw in the `storage.get().put(String.valueOf(i), "test");`, because in the another thread in the line `storage = new ThreadLocal<>();` was re-initialized.

Below presented code, where run two threads:

```
Collector collector = new Collector();
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println(collector.collection(1));
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println(collector.collection(2));
            }
        }).start();
```

How I can use the ThreadLocal to have local resource in each thread, which is independence from another threads?

Comment: Your method doesn't use any shared state except the ThreadLocal. It just creates a new, local HashMap and returns it. It would be thread safe if you didn't mess up with ThreadLocal. You don't need any ThreadLocal, any synchronization or anything for this method.

Comment: It is just example. It is necessary, because I need to create the resource, which is needed to use in another method in the Collector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-creating a new `ThreadLocal` instance each time the

```
collection(int)
```

method is called, with

```
this.storage = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

The `ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>>` can be a class `static` field

```
private final static ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>> STORAGE = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

To set and get the `Thread`'s associated value, just use

```
// You're better off passing and using an already constructed instance
STORAGE.set(new HashMap<>());
STORAGE.get();
```

Comment: @j6wj1997 Using the method get() of ThreadLocal. It will get what the current thread has previously stored using set(). That's the whole point of ThreadLocal.

Comment: @JBNizet added to the answer.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks FYI